# Is it possible to change the default language of google map in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dictionary, dart

I use geocoder in flutter for converting latlan to address. The address is in english How can I translate the given address to an other language for example Farsi

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
  var addresses =
      await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: no and i switch to the open street map in the flutter

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solve your issue.

Try this

```
...
var addresses =  await Geocoder.google('$YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY',language:YOU_LANG_CODE).findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Note that

YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY must be a valid [google api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key) already defined

YOU_LANG_CODE must be a valid language iso code [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes): ex. 'fa' in your case